# Rails 3 Update DB field on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am RoR beginner.
I'm building a small web app.In the App, users(unregistered) vote for a post.
In the Db table, there will be a field "Vote". In the view, there will be a "Vote" button.When user clicks this button, the vote field in the DB should be incremented by 1.
But, i don't understand how to bind the button click to increment action :(
Most of the material i have seen talks about saving entire model.But i could not come across an article where button clicks update DB field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do this you can use :

```
<%= link_to 'Vote', post, :method => :add_point, :remote=>true %>
```

add_point must be a method in your controller to increment by 1
You can see [rails-ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) for more infos

Comment: Ty Awea.An ty espescially for the link :)